# POST form keeps making GET request

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I created a form with only a submit button. Here is my code in the view:

```
<%= button_to searches_send_request_path, class: "btn btn-warning", id: "contact" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-envelope"> &nbsp; Send Request</i>
<% end %>
```

In the Chrome developer tool, it shows the form in HTML:

```
<form class="button_to" method="post" action="/searches/send_request"> 
  <button class="btn btn-warning" id="contact" type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"> &nbsp; Send Request</i>
  </button>
</form>
```

However, when I click the button, it keeps sending a GET request. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: can you add the rails form_for tag that you're using?

Comment: I don't have that. With button_to, I shouldn't need form_for. As you can see in the html section in my post, button_to would automatically generate a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML you provided submits form using POST, that's for sure. Probably you have some JS code replacing POST to GET.

Comment: I don't have any JS related to this page. Or is there any ways I can check it?

Comment: Try debugging it using Chrome console (F12). Check that the method is still GET. Check for errors in "console" tab, maybe there is some error preventing Rails ujs making its job.Then you might try checking the events binded on that form.

Answer (score 0):

[`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) defaults to `POST`...

> it will default to performing a `POST` operation

Since you've not explicitly set your `method` as `GET`, this suggests you have an issue higher up the browser stack.

---

A clue can be found within the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) documentation:

> Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET

Specifically, that your javascript is either disabled or erroneous; a common problem which results in the functionality you're experiencing.

--

The fix is to make **sure your Javascript is working properly**. The simplest way to do this is to load up the "developer console", to which you'll be able to see any errors in the Javascript.

In Chrome, you can `Right-Click > Inspect Element` - this will show the `console`, from which you'll be able to identify any of the errors your JS is returning:

[image]

If you do that, I'll be in a better position to help you resolve any of the issues it may have.