# Spring Boot with thymeleaf method not calling

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to call a java method with post mapping on a button click using form actions, I tried a lot, unfortunately, the method is not calling, shocking to me is that the nearly same code is working absolutely fine in some other project.

Here's the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    GenericClient client;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView createDashboardView(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("views/question");
        List<QuestionDTO> questions = client.genericClient(null, "question/fetchAllQuestions");
        QuestionsList questionsList = new QuestionsList();
        questionsList.setId1(questions.get(0).getId());
        questionsList.setQuestion1(questions.get(0).getDescription());
        questionsList.setId2(questions.get(1).getId());
        questionsList.setQuestion2(questions.get(1).getDescription());
        questionsList.setId3(questions.get(2).getId());
        questionsList.setQuestion3(questions.get(2).getDescription());
        modelAndView.addObject("questionsList", questionsList);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public ModelAndView onSaveClick(QuestionsList questionsList, BindingResult result){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("views/question");
        System.out.println("Inside method");

        System.out.println(questionsList.getQuestion2());

        return modelAndView;
    }



}
```

Here's the HTML file with Thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="views/master">

<body>
    <div layout:fragment="page-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT-->

            <div class="row-fluid errmsg"  id="dvError"
                visible="false">
                <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                    <div class="message success">
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <!-- BEGIN SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->
                    <div class="portlet box blue tabbable">
                        <div class="portlet-title">
                            <h4>
                                <i class="icon-reorder"></i><span class="hidden-480">Add/Edit
                                    Questions</span>&nbsp;
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="portlet-body form">
                            <div class="tabbable portlet-tabs">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">&nbsp;
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">

                                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="portlet_tab1">
                                        <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
                                        <div class="control-group"></div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mytable" style="overflow: auto;">
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <div class="controls questionMar01 questionColor ">
                                                <!--  Note:- Please enter @@ in your question where you want company name -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                        <form  class="form-horizontal"  action="#" th:action="@{/question/save}" th:object="${questionsList}" method="POST">

                                    <div>
                                        <input th:field="*{question1}" style="height:30px"  id="txtQuestion1"
                                            placeholder="Enter Question 1 Here" class="m-wrap large"
                                            type="text" /> 
                                            <br/><br/>
                                            <input th:field="*{question2}" style="height:30px"  id="txtQuestion2"
                                            placeholder="Enter Question 2 Here" class="m-wrap large"
                                            type="text"/>
                                            <br/><br/>
                                            <input  th:field="*{question3}" style="height:30px"  id="txtQuestion3"
                                            placeholder="Enter Question 3 Here" class="m-wrap large"
                                            type="text"  /> 
                                    </div>

                                        <div>&nbsp;</div>


                                        <div class="form-actions">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn blue okMark">Save</button>
                                            <!-- <button id="btncancel" class="btn cancel" 
                                                OnClick="btncancel_Click">Cancel</button> -->
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <!-- END FORM-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- END SAMPLE FORM PORTLET-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I'm trying to call /question/save/ post mapping on Save button click, unfortunately, onSaveClick method is not calling. Please help me out. Thanks

Project Structure:
[image: Project Structure]

Network tab after Save button click:
[image]

More information:

```
2018-01-18 17:40:15.741  INFO 9264 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/question/],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.beezyadmin.controller.QuestionController.createDashboardView()
2018-01-18 17:40:15.742  INFO 9264 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/question/save],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.beezyadmin.controller.QuestionController.onSaveClick(com.beezyadmin.dto.QuestionsList,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
```

/question/save is getting mapped as shown in the logs and also I'm able to call the method directly using PostMan, however, I'm unable to do so from Thymeleaf html page on Save button click.

Source code from view page source:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean the method is not getting called? any errors？ any other methods called instead?

Comment: @MinjunYu No errors, none of the method gets called, only the page refreshed. I want to call onSaveClick method on Save button click.

Comment: So after staring at the code snippets for half an hour, and tried some similar code, i think there is nothing wrong with the given code. please show us 1. your complete project structure; 2. your post request url. 3. browser's network info after post e.g. f12 network tab content.

Comment: @MinjunYu I have added project structure and network tab image after save button click. I don't know what you are expecting by post request url, as it is mentioned in th:action and @ PostMapping in the java code.

Comment: why is your updated screen shot not using th:action while your original post is using it.

Comment: @MinjunYu Because this screenshot is from chrome's view source screen, this is not the eclipse tab.

Comment: Really strange, onSaveClick always can be called on my computor.

Comment: @user27149 even on my other project everything is working fine. I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: Is it work now after remove the slash? what if you try another web browser?

Comment: In above **Network tab after Save button click** picture, it seems your browser send a request with parameter instead post data.

Comment: @user27149 It's not working even after removing the slash. Yes, I agree with your point that the browser is sending the request with parameter instead of post data. Could you please help me in resolving this? I don't know why is this happening.

Comment: I see some similar questions. Seems usually because open form tags or js functions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256505/html-form-send-data-by-get-instead-post,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653893/views-always-doing-an-http-get-instead-of-a-post-on-submit, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051312/post-form-keeps-making-get-request

Comment: @user27149 Turned out there's an issue with my master layout file, when I removed the master layout and used the only html for questions page then it worked normally. You really helped a lot, please post it as an answer so that I could accept your answer here. :)

Comment: This makes sense. I'm not a expert on front end, maybe you can upload your layout file and other static files so I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user27149 Issue is resolved buddy, as you helped me a lot I wanted to give a nice gesture. Probably, if you haven't pointed this out then I won't be able to figure this thing out at all.

Comment: @SiddharthSachdeva I edit my answer with the final solution. Still curious about the reason :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163453/discussion-between-siddharth-sachdeva-and-user27149).

Comment: @user27149 In the master layout file there was another form tag, it does have the closing tag however still it was causing some issue. So I removed opening and closing of form in master layout file and everything worked as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, there is something wrong the layout file, which causes clicking button perform an GET instead POST automatically for some reason.
[image]
After removing layout file every thing works.

Comment: Controller already has a "/question" mapping

Comment: The request might be postted to `http://localhost:8080/question/question/save` by some configuration.

Comment: @user27149 Still not working

Comment: @user27149 onSaveClick method gets called when I used PostMan to http://localhost:8080/question/save

Comment: Open the source code of webpage in web browser, see where actually the `button` will lead to.

Comment: @user27149 I have added the source code as well in question description, it doesn't look any strange to me, Although, even I think something wrong is happening due to html/events only.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller has mapping "/question/save"

**BUT**

Your th:action has a url of "/question/save/"

Watch out the trailing slash.

Comment: This is not the issue, the issue was with the master layout file. Thanks